# problems deploying a contract on the Kovan network

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, kovan, hardhat-deploy

Good evening, a couple of days ago I was able to execute this command without any problem and today, suddenly, I got this error. I don't understand what it means by "**insufficient funds**". Have there been any changes lately? Since when do I need funds to deploy the contract in a testnet? Does this refer to funds in the contract? How can I send funds to the contract if the contract has not been deployed?

The command: `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network kovan`

[image]

Comment: This means that you don't have enough Ether in your deploying address to pay for the transaction. Try getting some more Ether to that address via a Kovan Ether faucet.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize I was using another account on Metamask. Sorry for that. Thanks! (at least I know the error now)